# How to handle views and logic in a Winform C# app?

Tags: c#, software, architectural-patterns, winforms

I come from a webdev background so I'm used to MVC to handle the separation between the views and the logic (and the data/models).

I'm starting to develop using Winforms in C# and I want to know what's commonly used to develop a scalable, maintainable piece of software.

For example, if I want to make a bussines managament sofware, I'd have views for

- Clients
- Bills
- Invoices
- Sales
- Stock
- Appointments
- Taxes

etc.

I've searched and saw [this reply](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/277143/how-do-you-separate-view-from-logic-in-a-winform-application) that says you can use MVVM pattern.

Is this common for software development (especially big projects)?

Is there another pattern or paradigm I can learn to develop scalable, easy to maintain software?

Comment: The most common MVC pattern in Winforms is the Model-View-Presenter.

Comment: [Apologies for a borderline-appropriate comment.]  Since you are starting and you are aiming at large projects, could you skip the legacy WinForms and start with the mature WPF.  WinForms is a 16 year old framework.  WPF is only 9 years old.

Comment: @NickAlexeev, so Winforms is more mature than WPF ;)

Comment: The most common pattern in Winforms is the MVVM - Model View ViewModel

Comment: To add to @NickAlexeev's comment, ignoring the different in age, WPF was created with the needs of making Line Of Business apps first and foremost in its design philosophy.  "Business management software" is the bread and butter of what WPF is meant for.

Comment: https://github.com/mrts/winforms-mvp

Comment: @Fabio: I've never seen an MVVM Winforms app, so if it is the most common, it is very cleverly hidden.

Comment: @RobertHarvey  The distinctive operating principle in MVVM is that it uses *data binding*.  Data bindings can be used with WinForms, in theory.  In practice, WinForms doesn't have a friendly mechanism for establishing the data bindings.  [MVP doesn't use data binding.  It woudn't be inaccurate to say that, MVVM is MVP with data bindings.]

Comment: This question will probably closed as "too broad", but FWIW, look [here](http://codebetter.com/jeremymiller/2007/07/26/the-build-your-own-cab-series-table-of-contents/). That excellent series of blog posts teaches you how to develop an MVC architecture for something like a Winforms application.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, in my comment I tried to be ironic, because "most common" doesn't mean useful. Actually most common pattern for Winforms is "Code Behind" where sql queries are written in UI control handlers.

Comment: @NickAlexeev, you are right data-binding in Winforms not so powerful as in WPF, but is friendly enough to build proper MVVM implementation. Even better, you will be able to reuse same viewmodels later in WPF app.

Answer (score 2):

The pattern that was associated with winforms was the Model View Presenter pattern (MVP). So the answer to the question (which you didn't ask), "*what MVC-style design pattern should I use with winforms*?", is MVP. However, the MVP pattern, especially with winforms, is largely seen as a huge anti-pattern full of very bad practices, eg [see here for some details of its issues](http://blog.mattwynne.net/2007/06/13/mvp-smells/).

The MVVM pattern used by WPF apps in Windows is a much better pattern. However, it isn't easy to use with winforms.

And there's the rub: winforms is a very old technology. That link for example is from 12 years ago. Microsoft stopped active development of winforms many many years ago and modern ideas like MVVM do not work (well) with it.

So the answer to your actual question, "*what's commonly used to develop a scalable, maintainable piece of software*?", the answer is, "don't use winforms". Unless you absolutely have no choice, choose WPF and MVVM instead. Alternatively, if you are able to target just Windows 10, [UWP](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/get-started/universal-application-platform-guide) is also well worth considering.

If you are stuck with winforms, then you are pretty much on your own. Good luck...

Comment: That link is not so much an indictment of MVP as a list of ways that people implement it poorly.  MVP as a pattern is just fine.  I wouldn't call MVVM better or worse than MVP - just that some features in WPF lend themselves more to use with MVVM (e.g., commands and data templates).

Answer (score 0):

In C#, at least from my experience with WinForms, you'll want the logic to be separate from the GUI stuff. It looks like what you have there is very web-like. So, in that case MVC would work just fine. If you are using LINQ to handle your database work, keep those in a separate file/files, the logic in a separate file/files, and the forms/controls/etc by themselves as well.

Answer (score 0):

Coming from an MVC perspective, the best way to look at this is to consider the form logic as the controller, and the designer view as the view.

In web, you deal with separate stages. First the controller method runs and returns an HTML string, and then the browser displays the given HTML string. The controller thread dies when it's handled it's request.
Any new web request is considered an expensive operation, enough so that you generally want to minimize requests where reasonably possible.

In Winforms, the "controller" (i.e. form logic) stays alive and is attached to the view. It observes the view, and constantly interacts with it. It tracks events (e.g. clicking a certain button), and it can do other things like running background processes that automatically update the view.
Interaction between the "controller" and "view" are cheap, because they are both in-memory on the same machine. There is no expensive operation and interaction between the two is essentially the only way you can have your form be interactive.

But there is a slight catch: handling control events (like click events) quickly becomes a quite lengthy task (many methods), and therefore you are advised to keep your business logic separate from the actual "controller" code, simply to untangle the event wiring from the important logic.

---

In all cases, anything you would've separated outside of the MVC project (business logic, data access, ...), you should also separate outside of the Winforms project. In essence, MVC/Winforms should be interchangeable and both able to use the same business projects to provide the same functionality; without needing to change these business projects based on which frontend you're using.

---

But it's not as easy to tell you how these forms should be designed.

- At a base level, you can simply design separate windows for all views. This isn't the best user experience but it is usually what newcomers start off with.
- Before resorting to frameworks, you can simply design separate user controls for all views (think of this like a partial view with no layout page), and then you have one window which displays one control (= the view you currently want to show the user). This is analogous to having a main web page which then loads in partial views asynchronously based on what button the user clicks. It's still possible to open multiple instances of this "layout" window and display a user control in each of them, if you so choose.
- You can resort to frameworks such as [WinformsMVP](https://github.com/DavidRogersDev/WinformsMVP), many others exist. Which one you use is usually fairly subjective as to which one matches your preferred approach. These frameworks essentially provide you with an advanced template for interactions between your "views" and "controllers". Not everyone likes every framework, as they tend to require you to learn their specific way of doing things. It has its ups and downs, just like any other framework in any other context.

Which one you use very much depends on how you intend the application to behave. My experience has mostly been with separate windows for all edit/detail views (option 1), and user controls in a "layout" window for all search/list views (option 2); but this is partly because I was supporting a fairly old codebase in both instances where this was still the preferred user experience. More modern UIs tend to go for a much less window-heavy approach, but again it depends on the intended user experience.